# Discount Present Update When Quantity Change

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2017-express

I have table call `tblInvoice`. This is my table with some data.

| InvoiceNo | ItemName | Quantity | CostPrice | ItemCode | DiscountPrice | DisPresent | Amount | GrossAmount | SalePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INV01 | 80= BK | 10 | 30.00 | EX80= | 40.00 | 100.00 | 400.00 | 575.00 | 50.00 |
| INV01 | 80= BK | 5 | 30.00 | EX80= | 35.00 | 75.00 | 175.00 | 575.00 | 50.00 |

My client is sell same item with different price. as you can see here `DiscountPrice` is different but `ItemName` and `ItemCode` is same. When return product after sold I want to subtraction quantity. Its ok I already done that part. But problem is I want to update `DiscountPesent` after return product. its like this. Imagine I return 1 Book `DiscountPrice` is 40.00. Not 35.00. I want to update only first row. not both rows. I want to get DiscountPresent Like this.

```
SalePrice - DiscountPrice * Quantity = DiscountPresent
```

According to the above table. Imagine I subtraction 1 Quantity from DiscountPrice 40.00 row. now My Quantity is 9 I want to get DiscountPresent Like this.

```
50 - 40 = 10 * 9 = 90
```

I used following query for achieve this. sometimes its work as expected. but sometimes `DiscoutPresent` Switching with second row DiscountPeresent. After that table look like this.

| InvoiceNo | ItemName | Quantity | CostPrice | ItemCode | DiscountPrice | DisPresent | Amount | GrossAmount | SalePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INV01 | 80= BK | 9 | 30.00 | EX80= | 40.00 | 75.00 | 400.00 | 575.00 | 50.00 |
| INV01 | 80= BK | 5 | 30.00 | EX80= | 35.00 | 90.00 | 175.00 | 575.00 | 50.00 |

90 is come to second row. 75 is come to first row. its wrong. I used following code. sometimes its work as expected. but sometimes it switching `DiscountPresent`.

```
 UPDATE ps
SET DisPresent = ((i.SalePrice) - (i.DiscountPrice)) * (i.Quantity) 
FROM tblInvoice ps JOIN
     (SELECT i.InvoiceNo, i.DiscountPrice, i.Quantity, i.SalePrice  FROM tblInvoice i
     GROUP BY i.DiscountPrice, i.InvoiceNo, i.Quantity, i.SalePrice)i
     ON ps.InvoiceNo = i.InvoiceNo
```

Comment: what is the primary key for `tblInvoice `

Comment: @Squirrel InvoiceId is primary key

Comment: Then your update statement should be join on `InvoiceId` and the sub query should group by `InvoiceId` too

Comment: @Squirrel could you please change the code and send it back to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to me you only need a simple update statement

```
UPDATE i
SET    DisPresent  = (i.SalePrice - i.DiscountPrice) * i.Quantity
FROM   tblInvoice i
```

if this is not what you wanted, please show the expected result for the sample data that you have provided

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel. I used Primary key. Now its work. If i get that error again i will send my  updated code. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you are returning any product you should update only that invoice

```
UPDATE ps
SET DisPresent = ((i.SalePrice) - (i.DiscountPrice)) * (i.Quantity) 
FROM tblInvoice where invoiceid=1 and itemcode='EX80='
```

Comment: Thanks @squirrel. Since I am using my phone to answer formatting is not good.

Comment: Sqquirrel I have one problem. tblInvoice is one table. tblReturnInvoice is another table. When I insert data into tblReturnInvoice table I want to update this tblnvoice table. I use this in tblInvoice table trigger. therefor how can i get InvoiceId according to your answer

Comment: do you have invoice id in return invoice table?

Comment: And you have already updated the tblInvoice table already before running this query. Right?

Comment: No I don't have Invoice id in my return invoice table. According to the above update query i changed Join query to ON ps.InvoiceNo = i.InvoiceNo to ON ps.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId. now its working as expected. but sometimes its shows minus value for other rows data. its mean sometimes two rows update with same time.

Comment: would you please also add ps.itemcode=i.itemcode. it would be better to suggest if you can share table structure of both the tables.

Comment: I did it as you said. But sometimes unwanted rows also update. its mean when i return 1 item form book. my phone DiscountPresent also change. its shows - value

Comment: That's why I was looking for the table structures so that I can try to understand the issue. You might also mail me at kmnur@hotmail.com if you feel comfortable. Sample data for an invoice and returninvoice would be great.